# Adjust widget size according to window size using grid geometry and screen size

Tags: tkinter

I want to use grid geometry to change the size of widget according to size of window(maximize or minimize).

Example:

If a window is made and its look fulfilled in minimize mode but on expanding it shows some blank space .I want to expand the widget in such a way to fulfill that blank space.

If the LCD is changed the window should look same.It should also manage its size according to different LCD size
I used grid_rowconfigure and grid_columnconfigure methods, but in my program I am deleting one frame and then display another frame on that window...it works fine for the first frame but it doesn't work for the second frame and another problem is when I change my LCD screen to a smaller one, the widgets cannot be seen in a window as arranged in the bigger screen. The widget coincide with the border of window and some widgets disappear from window due to screen size.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can do it by `place` method, I think. Here's an answer for you...

Comment: Are you using the `sticky` option to grid`? Are you using `grid_rowconfigure` and/or `grid_columnconfigure`? Please show us an MCVE (http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to apply [`grid_rowconfigure()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_rowconfigure-method) and [`grid_columnconfigure()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_columnconfigure-method) on, respectively, the rows and columns of the parent/main widget where you draw the children `widgets`.

Example:

Suppose on the main window you draw 2 buttons on the the first row and first 2 columns. You will need to apply the methods above like this:

```py
    main_window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # For row 0
    main_window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # For column 0
    main_window.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1) # For column 1
```

The `columns` and `rows` of the parent/main `window` have a `weight` grid option associated with them. This option, which is by default set 0 (don't expand to fill space),  tells  how much the row/column should grow if there is extra room in the  `master` to fill.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

label = Label(root, text="Hello world!", bg='cyan')
label.place(relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.5)
```

?

Comment: The question specifically asked about `grid`.