# How to re-size Tkinter text entry widget using Grid?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been searching for the solution but I could not find one that works for me.
I'm trying to change the size of the entry widget using Grid, below is my current code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create application window
    app = Tk()

    # title
    app.title("Music Players")

    # geometry
    app.geometry('500x300')

    # background color
    app.configure(bg='orange')

    equation = StringVar()
    window_1 = Entry(app, textvariable=equation)
    window_1.grid(columnspan=5, ipadx=100, ipady=10)
    equation.set('Music Player')

    window_2 = Entry(app)
    window_2.grid(columnspan=5, ipadx=100, ipady=10)
    window_2.place(x=0, y=50, width=340, height=500)
```

I'm using **place** to adjust the size of window_2 entry, but it's hard to adjust it well, somehow the numbers using **place** do not match with the numbers in grid setting. How can I efficiently change the entry size using grid rather than place?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have used `grid` why do you use `place` agagin?

Comment: I could not find a way to adjust the size with grid... Whatever I searched online was not working such as padx, or height, text, etc....... Only thing I could get it worked was place.

Comment: "change the size" is awfully vague. Make it taller? Wider? Narrower?

Comment: _" somehow the numbers using place do not match with the numbers in grid setting"_ - correct. They are completely independent. When you call `place`, any changes from previously calling `grid` or `pack` are thrown away.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes to make it taller and wider. But in general, just change the size of text entry.. At this point, I'm not exactly sure how big or small my entry widget needs to be..... I was told that using grid is better than place, so I'm trying to use only grid...

Comment: To say you want to change the size of something with no other context, it's hard to give an answer. Typically you want to make the widget the size you want regardless of the use of `grid` or `pack`, and then they will try to make it fit. You seem to be asking how to do the opposite which isn't a natural thing to do. If you want the entry to be a specific size, why don't you just make it the size you want with the `width` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grid` and `pack` are designed around the idea that you create the widgets in their desired or optimal size. You then define their relative placement and `grid` or `pack` will adjust everything for you so that everything fits.

For the vast majority of situations, this works exceptionally well. I've worked with many GUI toolkits over a couple of decades, and no other toolkit ever come close to the power and simplicity of `pack` and `grid` IMHO.

If you want the entry widget to be wider, you can do that by setting the `width` attribute of the entry.

```
window_1 = Entry(app, textvariable=equation, width=20)
window_2 = Entry(app, width=20)
```

Once you've done that, `grid` and `pack` will do its best to allocate enough space to accommodate the widget. That is their advantage over `place`: they will do the calculations to make everything fit. With `place` it is entirely up to you to figure out how to make things fit.

You can then use the various options for `grid` and `pack` to make minor adjustments such as adding padding, having the widgets grow or shrink if the amount of available space changes, etc.

Comment: The reason I could not do this is that when I tried to use "height" to adjust, it gives me an error of: ```_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-height"```. So I'm assuming there is no simple way of adjusting both using Grid?

Comment: @sarahkim: correct: entry widgets can only be one character tall. What purpose do you have to make an entry widget taller than a character? You can use grid or pack options to stretch it taller, but it will still only be able to contain a single line of text.

Comment: Ahh okay, because I wanted to put text under whatever output text I get from the website.. for example, if I call an API for music, I wanted to show lyrics into the box. But I guess I will need to find the different option.

Comment: @sarahkim: are you wanting a multiline text widget? That would be a `Text` wiget. An `Entry` widget is specifically for a single line. A `Text` widget has both width and height options.

Answer (score 3):

Hello i ran the given code and following is the output

[image: IMAGE here]

## Use `Label` for HEADING

First of all if you intend to make a "MUSIC PLAYER" then you should use `Label` widget of Tkinter for the HEADING of the application instead of using `Entry` widget. The content of `Label` widget can not be edited by the user and its size and font can also be defined easily.

*The application you are working on might need a listbox not an Entry widget*

If you want an Entry widget in your program, You cannot use both `place` and `grid` on widgets that have the same master. The first one will adjust the size of the widget. The other will see the change, and resize everything to fit it's own constraints. The first will see these changes and resize everything again to fit its constraints. The other will see the changes, and so on ad infinitum. They will be stuck in an eternal struggle for supremacy.

Both `place` and `grid` can not be used simultaneously .Instead you can define two separate `frames` one for the heading and one for the mainentry and use `grid` in one and `place` in the other very easily.

Personally i will recommend you to use `.place()`
to set the width of entry widget you should use `relwidth = 0>x>1`
to set the width of entry height you should use `relheight = 0>x>1`
to Leave some space b/w top x-axis of your screen use `relx = 0>x>1`
to Leave some space b/w left y-axis of your screen use `rely = 0>x>1`
its very simple and you can surely rely on it

I rewrote your code using `.place()`

```
from tkinter import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create application window
    app = Tk()

    # title
    app.title("Music Players")

    # geometry
    app.geometry('500x300')

    # background color
    app.configure(bg='orange')

    equation = StringVar()
    window_1 = Label(app, textvariable=equation)
    window_1.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.1, relx=0.1, rely=0.05)
    equation.set('Music Player')

    window_2 = Entry(app)
    window_2.place(relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.7, relx=0.05, rely=0.2)


app.mainloop()
```

And this is the OUTPUT:
[image: image -2]

Hope it helps ....

Comment: When i started Tkinter many peaple also recommended me to use grid instead of place so i tried it but it was very confusing for me so i hopped back on using place. Its up to you to decide which method of "slamming widgets onto the screen" suits you.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the music player into the label. But I think I want to stick with grid, as I'm trying to change it to place, all my buttons are going places....

Comment: Okay as you wish

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.grid` to adjust height, just use place. It isn't good practice to use both `grid` and `pack`, as @BryanOakley said.

In place, there are two parameters which will help you. `relheight` and `relwdith`. These set the height and width relative to the size of the parent widget.

If you don't want to use place, you can use `grid_rowconfigure()` and `grid_widthconfigure()`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564649/adjust-widget-size-according-to-window-size-using-grid-geometry-and-screen-size).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, so for my previous project I was all using place, but a lot of feedback I heard was "use grid rather than place", so I'm only trying to use grid.. Is there an efficient way to adjust the size with grid?

Comment: I never said it's not a good practice to use both grid and pack. I simply said you _can't_ use both for a single widget. Only one can affect a widget at any one time.

Comment: Yes, @BryanOakley That is what I meant.

Comment: @sarahkim You can use the `grid_rowconfigure()` and `grid_widthconfigure()`, as stated in my answer.